# Angular directive from array element in ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on a project that will have any number of HTML cards, and the format and positioning of the cards is the same, but the content of them will differ.

My plan was to implement the content of each card as an angular directive, and then using ngRepeat, loop through my array of directives which can be in any order, displaying each directive in a card. It would be something like this:

inside my controller:

```
$scope.cards = [
    'directice-one',
    'directive-two',
    //etc..
]
```

my directive:

```
.directive('directiveOne', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "C",
        template: '<h1>One!!</h1>'
    };
})

.directive('directiveTwo', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "C",
        template: '<h1>Two!!</h1>'
    };
})

//etc..
```

my html:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="item in cards">
    <div class="{{item}}"></div>
</div>
```

But.. the directives don't render. So I just get a div with `class="directive-one"`.

This might be a design flaw on my part, some sort of syntax error, or just a limitation of angular. I'm not sure.

I've also considered making a directive `<card>`, and then passing the `templateUrl:` into it, but that would cause me to lose my access to `$scope` and the javsacript capabilities that I would have if each card was it's own directive.

So, advise, code help, anything would be very helpful!

Comment: Silly question but why don't you just pass an array of objects instead of an array of directives? Such as [{ foo: "bar", ... }] and then of course you can access the object from your template by doing item.foo etc...

Comment: @delashum, you need to understand that Angular will not substitute the elements with style classes with the directives they correspond to unless you tell it to explicitly (i.e. via `$compile`). Here's a simple demonstration of what I'm talking about — http://plnkr.co/edit/qf677nqrPhhW0ajSkVy5?p=preview Even so, I suggest you review your design.

Comment: @miqid Thanks for the help! I didn't know about `$compile` but it worked brilliantly! I agree this is not the best set up, but I'm just not sure what is. I guess I don't have the experience yet to be certain. Any simple suggestions for this sort of project?

Comment: @delashum, I'd actually advise the option you decided against. That is, creating one directive and injecting the necessary data in via attributes. If there is something in the governing `$scope` you need access to, you could refactor that into a service and then inject your directive with it, thus making it available. If that's still insufficient, you can consider communication via broadcasts on `$rootScope`, though do use this sparingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choose directives only when I need to use them in HTML mark up. For example, assuming cards layout is same and it takes different information based on user preference.

**HTML File**

```
<my-card Name="First" Option="Myoptions"></Card>
<my-card Name="Second" Option="GenOptions"></Card>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module("testapp").directive("MyCard", function() {
scope: {
 name: '@',
 Option: '@'
 Controller: "myCardController",
 templateURL: "~/myCard/myCardTemplate.html"
}
});
```

In Template you can implement the information passed from HTML page via the directive.

Hope this helps.

Do take note that the above approach is preferred when you are developing a framework sort of things. For example you develop a web framework and the header takes 5 parameters and these 5 parameters needs to be passed via mark up. Most important thing is that the framework/header is independent

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you need to require the directive modules. Then assign them to a scope variable which would be that array you have. Will update with code when I get to desktop, tried doing with phone kinda tuff.